# Error 500 with Login Process (SQL, PHP, Heroku)

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, login-script, cloud9

I'm trying to turn my final project into my teacher via pushing it from Cloud9 to Heroku. Unfortunately, the code managing the project's login process has a mistake that's preventing it from displaying most of my site to my teacher.

Here is the code

```
//login
    <?php
session_start();

 include 'dbConnection.php';
$conn = getDatabaseConnection();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
//echo $password;
//Watch out! Sql injection risk
/*$sql = "SELECT *
FROM q_admin
WHERE username = '$username'
AND password = '$password'";*/

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM f_admin
WHERE username = :username
AND password = :password";

$namedParameters  = array();
$namedParameters[':username']  = $username;
$namedParameters[':password']  = $password;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($namedParameters);
$record = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



if (empty($record)) {
    echo "Wrong username or password";
    header("Location: login.php?login=false");
    exit; 

} else {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $record['username'];
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $record['userId'];
    header('Location: admin.php'); //redirects users to admin page
}

?>
```

The code above should be looking into my SQL database for usernames and passwords before deciding whether or not to let the user into the site's admin page.

Instead, the user is taken to a mostly blank page displaying an error 500, regardless of their credentials.

According to the Heroku logs, the error is somewhere around line 24, but I still can't identify it.

Thank you for giving this your time.

Comment: `guess the error text` game, coool!

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: You should always check for [PDO errors](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php), the issue may be something to do with your queries.